# Where should I report http500 bug in bing.com?

Tags: microsoft

I found a way to easily get HTTP 500 Internal Server Error directly from https://bing.com/ site with proper query. It seems to be 100% reproducible.

Should I report it? Where?

I found site for reporting bugs in Microsoft products, but for [bing](http://connect.microsoft.com/directory/?keywords=bing) keyword it only finds bingmaps product.

**update:**
yes - I did google that before asking. I didn't find any reasonable answer to my question.

Why I ask here it's because It can be related to security issue.
If server do not handle properly such queries (i.e. google returns http 400 for such queries) it makes it probable that some important process dies on one node for every query. If this is the case, it's easy to DOS this big service. It's of course just a speculation, but this is why decided to ask this community.

**Update2:**

Microsoft was happy to receive this information via secure@microsoft.com as I mentioned in my [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/100230/3897).

[image]

Comment: at right-hand corner, feedback would be fine!

Comment: @SbSangpi, that was my first guess, but it's one-directional contact, they ask not to provide email and I think report may be lost in tons of "what a cute wallpaper" feedbacks.

Comment: @MichałŠrajer It's important to explain what steps you already took to find an answer so that we don't end up suggesting something that you think is 'obvious'

Comment: @schroeder in question I wrote "I found site ..." using google with exactly same query as in "did you try google" (deleted) comment.

Answer (score 1):

secure@microsoft.com seems to be the right place to go according to:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/ff852094.aspx

**Update:**
I got reply from MSRC folks. They asked for details, so it seems to be indeed right place to report such issue.